# Retrieve the ID from the value returned by the stored procedure

Tags: c#

I want to retrieve the ID from the value returned by the stored procedure and put it into our DataSet. This is the code in VB how to translate it in C # .
Thanks in advance

```
oRow("ProductId") = cmdCommand.Parameters.Item("@ProductId").Value
```

Comment: `oRow["ProductId"] = cmdCommand.Parameters["@ProductId"].Value` or something?

Comment: Soner Gönül is correct. @Amater90 : you can find a VB from/to C# converter here http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score -1):

Another "easy" way to do it would be to use IL SPY to see the code from the DLL then to display it as C#